# Drag an UIImageView from UIscrollView to another view

Tags: objective-c, uiview, drag-and-drop, uiscrollview, uiimageview

I crawled all the web, but nothing.

I have a *for loop* to *create uiimageview inside a uiscrollview controller*.
It's a collection of images that you can scroll *horizontally only*.

```
for (int i = 0; i < NIMAGES; i++) {
    NSString *filename = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"image%d.png", i+1];
    ScrollerImage *iv = [[ScrollerImage alloc] initWithNibName:@"ScrollerImage" bundle:nil];
    [iv initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:filename]];
    iv.frame = CGRectMake(i * 320.0f, 0.0f, 320.0f, 150.0f);
    iv.exclusiveTouch = YES;
    iv.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    [sv addSubview:iv];
    [iv release];
}
```

The **ScrollerImage** class is an **UIImageView controller**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface ScrollerImage : UIImageView { 
}
@end
```

**Now, how can I drag** (not necessary a move, also a copy of view, or an id of view, anything that permit me to identify the image) **an image from the scroller to another view**?
It's like a shopping cart, where you can drag items at the bottom view (cart).

Like this:
[image]

Comment: This response to a similar question should help anyone else looking for guidance on this topic: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7444231/ios-drag-and-drop-between-scroll-views/7969538#7969538](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7444231/ios-drag-and-drop-between-scroll-views/7969538#7969538)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an alternative, using `UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()`

You can grab an image from currentScreen on click or after some events. Next renderize it to screen and apply a Pan gesture to move around the screen.

```
UIView *_DraggableView;
UIImageView *_imgvcChild1;
```

sample code:

```
- ( void ) onScrollviewClickOrOtherEvent
{
  UIGraphicsBeginImageContext ( _DraggableView.frame.size );
  [ _DraggableView.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() ];

  UIImage *grab = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
  UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

  if ( _imgvcChild1 ) [ _imgvcChild1 removeFromSuperview ];
  _imgvcChild1 = [[ UIImageView alloc ] initWithImage:grab ];
  _imgvcChild1.frame = _DraggableView.frame;
  _imgvcChild1.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
  [ self.view addSubview:_imgvcChild1 ];

  UIPanGestureRecognizer *pan = [[ UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc ] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(moveObject:) ];
  [ pan setMinimumNumberOfTouches:1 ];
  [ _imgvcChild1 addGestureRecognizer:pan ];
}

- (void) moveObject:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)pan
{
  _imgvcChild1.center = [ pan locationInView:_imgvcChild1.superview ];
}
```

**--- EDIT ---**

A sample project on github: https://github.com/elpsk/Shopping-Cart

Answer (score 0):

I've been trying to implement this in an app of mine and I had to just give up. I subclassed `UIImageview` like you have as well(which is a good option) and all my images are on a UIView that is a subclass of `UIScrollView`. You can pass your viewcontroller to the images themselves and change which view the imageview is a subview to when it reaches a certain boundary (I overrided the `touchesMoved` on the `ImageViews` themselves). The problem with this is it doesn't drag continously. The user has to literally select the image again when they dragged the image across a certain point because you're literally switching the uiimageview from one view to another.

I hope this gives you some insight at least, I really haven't found a solution to this issue. You'd think a lot of IPad apps would be paving the way to drag images all over different views and more tutorials appear on the issue!