# Dragging a button from UITableView

Tags: ipad, ios4, uitableview, uigesturerecognizer

I have a TableView made up of a custom cell. This cell contains a label and a button. Now I have a **panGestureRecognizer** **added to the button in the cell.** My problem is when I try to start moving/dragging the button, the button moves correctly but unfortunately the button gets hidden behind the TableView. How can I make it to come in front of it. The custom cell is created programmatically and so is the TableView. My gesture handling method is as follows:

---

`-(void)panPiece:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer withEvent:(id) event
{`

```
UIView *piece = [gestureRecognizer view];
[self adjustAnchorPointForGestureRecognizer:gestureRecognizer];

//*******************Dragging Ended*************************************

if([gestureRecognizer state]==UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded)
{
    [tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0] atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionBottom animated:YES];

}

//*******************Dragging Started andchanged*************************************

if ([gestureRecognizer state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan || [gestureRecognizer state] ==UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged) 
{

    CGPoint translation = [gestureRecognizer translationInView:[piece superview]];
    [piece setCenter:CGPointMake([piece center].x + translation.x, [piece center].y + translation.y)];
    [gestureRecognizer setTranslation:CGPointZero inView:[piece superview]];
    CGPoint moveLocation=[gestureRecognizer locationInView:piece];
    NSIndexPath *indexPath=[tableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:moveLocation];
```

}

-(void)adjustAnchorPointForGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer
{
    if (gestureRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan || (gestureRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged)) 
    {
        UIView *piece = gestureRecognizer.view;
        CGPoint locationInView = [gestureRecognizer locationInView:piece];
        CGPoint locationInSuperview = [gestureRecognizer locationInView:piece.superview];
        piece.layer.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(locationInView.x / piece.bounds.size.width, locationInView.y / piece.bounds.size.height);
        piece.center = locationInSuperview;
    }
}


The code has been modelled based on apple's code [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/Touches/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007435)

Answer (score 0):

Here the solution: [Drag an UIImageView from UIscrollView to another view](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3960960/88461)

hope this helps

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I have already implemented this with the help of an image view. But the requirements are such that they compel me to drag the button rather than an image of it. When I am adding an image it is being added in the main view,i.e., self.view and ergo it works fine. But in case of a button embedded inside a tableview it gets rather complicated.Is there any other way to add the button other than adding it on the tableview cell's content view?