# Drag & drop UIView to other view to delete itself

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

I'm sub classing an UIView to make its always floating on my app's screen.  I'm using some method of `NSResponder` like `touchesMove`, `touchesEnd`... to make this view can movable. 
When I'm long press on this floating view another view called "Close View" will appear at bottom of screen. 
Now I want whenever I'm drag & drop this floating view to Close View this will be remove from superview (this will look like Android launcher when you delete an app from screen). But I don't know how to calculate when 2 view was reached to remove the floating view.
 Can someone help me to solve this problem? I've put a picture for imagination.
Update:
Here is my code:

```
- (BOOL)isTrashViewReached {
CGFloat distanceFromTrashView = sqrt(pow(self.center.x - self.trashView.center.x, 2) + pow(self.center.y - self.trashView.center.y, 2));
return distanceFromTrashView < self.bounds.size.width / 2;
}

-(void)updateTrashView {
    UIColor *trashColor = self.isTrashViewReached ?  [UIColor whiteColor] : [UIColor colorWithRed:174/255.0 green:0 blue:0 alpha:1];
    [self.deleteButton setTitleColor:trashColor forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

From [Drag an UIImageView from UIscrollView to another view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3960960/drag-an-uiimageview-from-uiscrollview-to-another-view) , it will be a great example for you.

Try it:

This is an alternative, using `UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()`

You can grab an image from currentScreen on click or after some events. Next renderize it to screen and apply a Pan gesture to move around the screen.

```
UIView *_DraggableView;
UIImageView *_imgvcChild1;
```

sample code:

```
- ( void ) onScrollviewClickOrOtherEvent
{
  UIGraphicsBeginImageContext ( _DraggableView.frame.size );
  [ _DraggableView.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() ];

  UIImage *grab = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
  UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

  if ( _imgvcChild1 ) [ _imgvcChild1 removeFromSuperview ];
  _imgvcChild1 = [[ UIImageView alloc ] initWithImage:grab ];
  _imgvcChild1.frame = _DraggableView.frame;
  _imgvcChild1.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
  [ self.view addSubview:_imgvcChild1 ];

  UIPanGestureRecognizer *pan = [[ UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc ] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(moveObject:) ];
  [ pan setMinimumNumberOfTouches:1 ];
  [ _imgvcChild1 addGestureRecognizer:pan ];
}

- (void) moveObject:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)pan
{
  _imgvcChild1.center = [ pan locationInView:_imgvcChild1.superview ];
}
```

A sample project on github: https://github.com/elpsk/Shopping-Cart

Answer (score 0):

You can convert a point from one views coordinates to another with the UIView.convert family of methods.  You can test if a rect contains a point or if two rects intersect with the methods on CGRect.  Here I check if the center of the dragging view is inside of the target rect:

```
    let convertedCenter = targetView.convert(draggingView.center, from: draggingView)
    if targetView.frame.contains(convertedCenter) {

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use CGRectIntersectsRect ,CGRectContainsRect or CGRectContainsPoint founction to do this.

```
if (CGRectContainsRect(deleteView.frame, selectedView.frame)) {
    NSLog(@"true");

}else{
    NSLog(@"false");

}
```